# How long did Saphira stay in her egg from the day it was laid by her mother?

Tags: dragons, inheritance-cycle

How long did Saphira stay in her egg from the day it was laid by her mother?

Comment: see the edit I just made to my answer, should be in time for your deadline

Answer (score 5):

### A little bit over 100 years

Saphira was born shortly before the Fall of the Dragon Riders

> **Was Saphira's egg laid immediately before/during the Fall, or did it happen a significant amount of time before that?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *It was laid fairly close to the Fall.*
>
> <sub>[Twitter, May 31 2022](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1531825163850772480)</sub>

The Fall of the Dragon Riders ended one hundred years before Eragon found Saphira's egg.

So Saphira spent a bit over 100 years in the egg. Perhaps something like 105 years.